# AVRO file not read fully by Spark

Tags: apache-spark, avro, spark-avro

I am reading AVRO file stored on ADLS gen2 using Spark as following:

```
import dbutils as dbutils
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

file="abfss://eventhub_user@mydatalake.dfs.core.windows.net/xyz-event-collection/my-events/27/2021/11/01/01/01/01.avro"
key="..........."
appName = "MyEventsReadTest"
master = "local[*]"
sparkConf=SparkConf() \
    .setAppName(appName) \
    .setMaster(master) \
    .set("fs.azure.account.key.dechitraguptdatalake.dfs.core.windows.net", key)

spark=SparkSession.builder.config(conf=sparkConf).getOrCreate()
df=spark.read.format("avro").load(file)
df.show()
```

I submit this `readEventsFromADLS2.py` file as following:

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:2.4.8 --jars hadoop-azure-3.3.1.jar  ./readEventsFromADLS2.py
```

However, I get only shortened output as a result.

```
21/11/15 13:21:03 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 13.582867 ms
+--------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+
|SequenceNumber|  Offset|     EnqueuedTimeUtc|    SystemProperties|Properties|                Body|
+--------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+
|         31411|21976208|11/10/2021 12:11:...|{x-opt-enqueued-t...|        {}|[7B 22 70 61 79 6...|
|         31412|21977032|11/10/2021 12:11:...|{x-opt-enqueued-t...|        {}|[7B 22 70 61 79 6...|
|         31413|21977736|11/10/2021 12:12:...|{x-opt-enqueued-t...|        {}|[7B 22 70 61 79 6...|
|         31414|21977800|11/10/2021 12:12:...|{x-opt-enqueued-t...|        {}|[7B 22 70 61 79 6...|
|         31415|21978336|11/10/2021 12:12:...|{x-opt-enqueued-t...|        {}|[7B 22 70 61 79 6...|
|         31416|21978872|11/10/2021 12:12:...|{x-opt-enqueued-t...|        {}|[7B 22 70 61 79 6...|
|         31417|21979632|11/10/2021 12:12:...|{x-opt-enqueued-t...|        {}|[7B 22 70 61 79 6...|
+--------------+--------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+

21/11/15 13:21:03 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

Questions:

1. How do I get to print fully expanded column in the above output?
2. How do I see the `Body` section (last column in the above output) in the text format? Body is actually a JSON, but coming as byte array here.

When I changed the df.show() to `df.show(10,False)` , I still get binary byte array representation for the `Body` field:

> |31411         |21976208|11/10/2021 12:11:46 PM|{x-opt-enqueued-time
> -> {1636546306366, null, null, null}}|{}        |[7B 22 70 61 79 6C 6F 61 64 22 3A....]

Comment: Use: df.show(false)

Comment: @NirHedvat  using df.show(false) throws following error:
    df.show(false)
NameError: name 'false' is not defined

Comment: For Scala: false, for Python: False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fully display all of the column you can use:

```
df.select("body").show(false)
```

If the data really is JSON and you want it read is JSON, [consider specifying the schema](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema) instead of letting Spark interpret it for you.

Comment: I get following error when I use `df.show(false)` :

`    df.show(false)
NameError: name 'false' is not defined`

Comment: When I change to ` df.show(False) ` then I see following error:

   
`  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.0/libexec/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 488, in show
TypeError: Parameter 'n' (number of rows) must be an int
`

Comment: so that is a different problem than what you originially asked.  I suggest that you update your query to look at body specficially df.select("body").show(false) as I modeified my answer.  This will let you see the data you oringinally asked for.  I would then likely do some data cleaning to find out the issue with your 'n' data.  But again that's a different issues.

Comment: `df.select("body").show(10,False)` does print only the `body` part, but it still prints byte as hex codes.

Comment: Yes, and that makes sense, consider specifying the schema so that it's presented in the format you wish it to be presented.